# Passing props in axios to Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, laravel, vuejs2, axios

I want to pass props from a parent component to a child component. My prop is `tid`.

This is the parent component:

```
<div id="tracksec" class="panel-collapse collapse">
    <library :tid="track.category_id"></library>
</div>
```

This is the child component:

```
<script>
import Chapter from "./chapter";
import Http from "../../services/http/httpService";
export default {
    components: {Chapter},
    props:['tid'],
    name: "library",
    data(){
        return{
            library:{},
        }
    },
    computed:{
      getPr(){
          return this.$props;
      }
    },
        mounted(){
      console.log(this.$props);
        Http.get('/api/interactive/lib/' + this.tid)
            .then(response => this.library = response.data)
            .catch(error => console.log(error.response.data))
    }
}
```

This is the http source:

```
import axios from 'axios';


class httpService {

static get(url, params) {
    if (!params) {
        return axios.get(url);
    }
    return axios.get(url, {
        params: params
    });
}

static post(url, params) {
    return axios.post(url, params);
}
}

export default httpService;
```

I want to pass the `tid` value to the `http.get` function. For example:

```
Http.get('/api/interactive/lib/' + this.tid)
```

However the `tid` value is `undefined`.
How do I get `tid` in the mounted or created hook?

Comment: All looks right to me. Is the `track.category_id` defined in your parent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm new to Vue, but I think you might want to add a "watcher" that triggers on change. Your "track-object" is empty on create, this leading track.category_id being undefined. Then when you get an answer from your HTTP get, your value is set, but not updated in the library component.

Something like this:

```
<script>
import Chapter from "./chapter";
import Http from "../../services/http/httpService";
export default {
    components: {Chapter},
    props:['tid'],
    name: "library",
    data(){
        return{
            library:{},
        }
    },
    watch: {
        // if tid is updated, this will trigger... I Think :-D
        tid: function (value) {
          console.log(value);
            Http.get('/api/interactive/lib/' + value)
            .then(response => this.library = response.data)
            .catch(error => console.log(error.response.data))
        }
      },
    computed:{
      getPr(){
          return this.$props;
      }
    },
        mounted(){
      console.log(this.$props);
      
      // Will be undefined
      /*
        Http.get('/api/interactive/lib/' + this.tid)
            .then(response => this.library = response.data)
            .catch(error => console.log(error.response.data))*/
    }
}
</script>
```

[Documentation about watchers](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers)

(Cant test the code, but you might get the idea)

Comment: Anonymous: Why down vote on this without any comment?

Answer (score 1):

In the parent component try to this code snippets

```
<div id="tracksec" class="panel-collapse collapse">
  <library tid="track.category_id"></library>
</div>
```

And then in your child component code will be look like this:

```
<script>
  import Chapter from "./chapter";
  import Http from "../../services/http/httpService";
  export default {
    components: {
      Chapter
    },
    props: [ 'tid' ],
    name: 'library',
    data () {
      return {
         library: {},
      }
    },
    computed: {
      getPr () {
          return this.tid;
      }
    },
    mounted () {
      const tidValue = this.tid // get the value of props you've passed
      console.log(tidValue) // check if it is getting the right value.
      // code for http request.
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: tid is dynamically not static is my project.

Comment: @Mohammadnajjary that is dynamic, only the name of props will be static right ?, the value of `tid` is dynamic

Comment: your answer is undefined

Answer (score 0):

this is parent script section:

```
   import Library from "./library";
import Http from '../../services/http/httpService';

export default {
    components: {Library},
    name: "interactive",
    data() {
        return {
            track: {},
        }
    },

    mounted() {
        Http.get('/api/interactive/track/' + this.$route.params.id)
            .then(response => this.track = response.data)
            .catch(error => console.log(error.response.data))
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you used the script that I've provided? You can check the props that you have passed by using `this.youPropsName`, you said that "i want pass tid value to http.get function ". You can check the value of `tid` by using `this.tid` in child component placing in `mounted ()` or `created ()` life cycle hooks of Vue

Comment: I did exactly that, but this.tid is undefined.

Comment: Have you tried to check if the value of `track.category_id` is not undefined?